# What is this "No Hand Hold" thing in the P-51 Mustang cockpit?

Tags: aircraft-design, fighter, p-51

Does Anybody remember Combat Flight Simulator WW2 Europe Series ?
In the P-51, there is a "something" with "No hand hold" text on top of it
What is that ?[image: The Thing]
Image [source](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/microsoft-combat-flight-simulator-wwii-europe-series-a3o)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is part of the [gyroscopic gun sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyro_gunsight):

[image]
<sub>Source: [WarRelics Forum](http://www.warrelics.eu/forum/airborne-special-forces/p-51-mustang-gyroscopic-gun-sight-k-14c-398722/)</sub>

It is not a "hand hold" because you don't want to damage the sight by grabbing the scope to situate yourself in the cockpit (getting in/out) or otherwise pulling on it. Since it is aligned to your guns, you would want to avoid misaligning it.

Comment: I think it's an important point that the part gives the strong impression of being a handle, and is just in the right place when you need something to hold on. The handle-like shape, I assume, is caused by making it round to be non-hazardous when hit with the head.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It also looks to be padded, but I've never encountered one in person to verify.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel So basically, a very bad piece of user experience design based on… Dunno.

Comment: Yes, based on bad luck, I would say. I do not see how it could be fixed, in a technical way.  But wait - it could indeed be fixed on a purely user experience design level! Just make it look very different. Basically camouflage the "handlelikeness".

Comment: Presumably the "no hand hold" message was added after quite a few sights had become misaligned. For UX, you could paint it to look spiky, or just cover it in black and yellow stripes.

Comment: Aren't military vehicles, particularly planes, generally quite liberally decorated with text like "don't step", "don't push" and the aforementioned "no hand hold"..?

Comment: You'll see these in general aviation planes, too. Here's a [Grumman AA5B](https://www.cirruspilots.org/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/00-13-01-00-00-32-58-63/2_2D00_55763_2D00_newpanel.jpg) cockpit.

Answer (score 6):

It's Mk14 lead computing gyro gunsight.  Designed by the Brits, and credited with increased accuracy / higher kill ratio (it took a lot of the guessing out of shooting).  The padded part with "No hand hold" stenciled on it, was in fact padded to protect the pilots face / head from impact during a crash or crash landing.  The Mustang did not have modern inertia reals on the shoulder straps (they could be locked up manually by the pilot).